# Trying to setup Astar zkEVM Mainnet Permissionless RPC Node but failed

Tags: json-rpc, rpc, mainnet, astar

I am trying to setup Astar zkEVM Mainnet Permissionless RPC Node following these [docs](https://docs.astar.network/docs/build/zkEVM/zk-node/setup-mainnet-rpc-node/), but it's not working for me. Looks like the container **zkevm-rpc** is not functioning.

```bash
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id":1, "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method": "eth_chainId", "params": []}' http://localhost:8545
```

```bash
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer.
```

Logs of container **zkevm-rpc** is likely below:

```js
{"level":"fatal","ts":1711103787.464334,"caller":"cmd/run.go:276","msg":"failed to connect to `host=zkevm-state-db user=state_user database=state_db`: dial error (timeout: dial tcp 172.25.0.2:5432: connect: connection timed out)"}
```

I can connect **postgresql** with the corresponding `db_user`, `db_password` and `db` using `localhost` from outside the container. I'm using my own ethereum `RPC_URL` which is syncing properly.

Does anyone have any idea what am I missing?